# Hibernate(Java Configuration) - no persistence units parsed from classpath* meta-inf/persistence.xml spring?

Tags: spring, hibernate, configuration, spring-data, vaadin7

in my Vaadin-Project configured the Spring, now trying to set up giberneyt, and read on the forums - all recommend to add a folder and file. That is understandable, but why? I want all configuration register in java-file.

Here is my config file.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ApplicationInitializer.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.jdev.blog.admin.crud.repositories")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.show_sql";

    @Resource
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        dataSource.setUrl(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        dataSource.setUsername(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        dataSource.setPassword(env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    private Properties hibProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO,
                env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_HBM2DDL_AUTO));
        properties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, env.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Error at startup.

```
20:51:23,476 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactor
y' defined in class com.jdev.blog.admin.config.ApplicationConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553) [spring-beans-4.0.6.RELEASE.jar:4.0.6.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `emfb.setPackagesToScan("com.package.entity")` to insead of `persistence.xml`

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,
                                                                   JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb =
            new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    emfb.setDataSource(dataSource);
    emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    emfb.setPackagesToScan("com.package.entity");
    return emfb;
}
```